# $g(x) = \lim \limits_{t \to x}f(t)$. Show $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Let the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to c}f(x)$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = \lim \limits_{t \to x}f(t)$. Show $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried the different proof comparing the method solution suggested. From here my proof begins.

$(pf)$
Fixed $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$, Say $\lim \limits_{x \to c}f(x) = g(c)$.

By definition,
For all $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ $s.t.$  $\forall x(0 < \vert x-c \vert <\delta  \Rightarrow \vert f(x) - g(c) \vert < \epsilon )$ ($*$).

Considering the $ I = \{x \vert \vert x-c \vert <\delta \}$

$\vert g(x)-g(c) \vert = \vert \lim \limits_{t \to x}f(t) - \lim \limits_{t \to x}g(c) \vert = \vert \lim \limits_{t \to x}(f(t)-g(c)) \vert <\epsilon$ , $\forall x \in I$ by the $(*)$

Hence $g$ is continuous at $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$ (In other words, $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$)

Is my proof right? If not, Please let me know which point I made mistakes.

Regards.

Comment: $\vert \lim \limits_{t \to x}(f(t)-g(c)) \vert <\epsilon$ why?

Comment: It is corect but just note that $<\epsilon$ becomes $\leq \epsilon$ in the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $c\in \mathbb{R}$, and define the punctured neighborhood $V_{c}=(c-\delta_c,c+\delta_c)\setminus\{c\}$

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta_c>0, \forall t\in V_{c} , \Rightarrow |f(t)-g(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}2$$

Next, $\forall x\in V_{c}$, since $\lim_{t\to x}f(t)=g(x)$, define the punctured neighborhood $V_{x}=(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\setminus\{x\}$

$$\exists \delta_x>0, \forall t\in V_{x}, |f(t)-g(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Finally, since $V_{c}\cap V_{x}\neq\emptyset$,  take  $t_1\in V_{c}\cap V_{x}$

$$\begin{align}
|g(x)-g(c)|&=|g(x)-f(t_1)+f(t_1)-g(c)|\\
\\
&\le|g(x)-f(t_1)|+|f(t_1)-g(c)|<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my proof

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @MathFail: To show that $g$ is continuous at $c$ you need to show that given $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta$ s.t whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ you have $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$. You take $\delta = \delta_1+\delta_2$. But when $|x-c| <\delta$, how can you conclude that  $|x-t|+|t-c| <\delta$? also, why does this imply that $|x-t| < \delta_1$ and $|t-c|<\delta_2$? (which you need to conclude that $|g-t|<\epsilon/2$ and $|f-g|<\epilon/2)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have revised the proof, thank you! @Harry

Comment: Note you really need $V_c$ and $V_x$ to be punctured neighborhoods (i.e. $V_c = (c-\delta_c, c+\delta_c) \setminus \{c\}$).  Otherwise, the same argument could show that $f$ is continuous, which may be false.

Comment: Right, it is edited, thank you! @BrianMoehring

Comment: @MathFail: If you want to prove that $g$ is continuous at a point $c$ don't you think you need to find a neighborhood of the point $c$ s.t the values of $g$ in that nbd are "close" to $g(c)$ ?  Is $V_c \cap V_x$ a nbd of $c$?

Comment: @Harry I don't get your point.  $V_c$ is a punctured neighborhood of $c$ and the inequality holds for any $x \in V_c$ (and it trivially holds for $x=c$).  The $t_1 \in V_c \cap V_x$ is just some value close enough to both $c$ and $x$ so that both $|f(t_1)-f(x)|$ and $|f(t_1) - f(c)|$ are sufficiently small -- it doesn't matter what $V_c \cap V_x$ is as long as it's nonempty.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Right, I think i misread $V_c \cap V_x$ as the nbd of $c$. So for an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument (as in the  earlier answer of MathFail) I could take $\delta$ to be anything  $ \le  \delta_c$ (so that i have $|g(x)-g(c)| <\epsilon whenever $|x-c|<\delta), right?

Comment: @Harry Yes.   (And in before any comments/questions, my last comment had a typo writing $f(x), f(c)$ instead of $g(x), g(c)$)